# How to Send flask-WTF form data to base.html in flask to use it in multiple pages for login modal

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I have created a form using flask-WTF, now if I want to send it to login page, I can simply do that by

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
            # validating logic
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)  # Render the login page
```

Now this renders a whole login page in which I can use my form data that I just sent as form=form.

But what if I wanted a modal pop up for log in and sign up. As I am using flask, I am using base.html that contains my login button and I extend this base.html in all other html files, if I want to send the form data in base.html file, how would I do it. I mean for sending the data I would have to render it which I don't want, I just want to show modal which I will create in base.html. Or else I would have to send form to each and every page I want to show Login modal in.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I couldn't think of anything as if I were to send form data to base.html, I would have to render it which I don't want.